# solving simple trigonometric equation: $\sin(53+\varphi) = \sin(53)$

Tags: trigonometry

Yea, it's as simple as that. Unfortunately I just manage to solve these equations when inverse functions can be applied. This isn't one of those. I realise the solution has something to do with $\varphi + 53 + 53 = 180$ hence $\varphi = 74$ But why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Prosthaphaeresis](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html)  formula

$$\sin(x+53^\circ)-\sin53^\circ=2\sin\dfrac{x+53^\circ-53^\circ}2\cos\dfrac{x+53^\circ+53^\circ}2$$

So, we have the product of two terms is zero.

What can we conclude from here?

Comment: Well, $0$ also is a solution but it's not the only one. But I see, $\cos\left(\frac{180^\circ}{2}\right) = 0$

Comment: @Leon, How many solutions are there for $$\cos y=0?$$ or $$\sin y=0?$$

Comment: for $\sin(y)$ it might be just $0$ but for $\cos(y)$ probably $74^\circ + n\,360^\circ$.

You've got a nice formula there

Answer (score 2):

In general, $$\sin x=\sin y \iff x=n\pi +(-1)^n y $$

You need $$53+\varphi = n\pi + (-1)^n 53 $$

For even $n=2k$, $$\varphi = 2k\pi $$

For odd $n=2k+1$, $$\varphi=(2k+1)\pi-106 $$